# Selecting Many-to-Many DQL in Doctrine 2.0

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 3 entities Building, Area and Route with this many2many associations:

Building n:m Area
Building n:m Route

An Area and a Route have a property visible.
I have to extract a Building and it associated visible Areas and Routes (if exists)

```
SELECT 
    b, bir, bia
FROM 
    ArchMapsBundle:Building b 
    LEFT JOIN 
        b.buildingsInRoute bir
    LEFT JOIN 
        bir.itinerario r WITH r.visible = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
        b.buildingsInArea bia
    LEFT JOIN 
        bia.area a WITH a.visible = 1
WHERE 
    b.id = :building_id
```

But I always get also areas and routes not visible.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that happens because some of your `JOIN`s pull entities without conditions. So, try this:

```
WHERE b.id = :building_id 
  AND r.visible = 1 
  AND a.visible = 1
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. If there are no area or routes, no Building is returned.